# update variable based on self-calling setTimeout based function

Tags: javascript, function, variables, settimeout

I'm trying to create a "typewriter" function and use it to define a variable, so that each character is added individually based on a timeout function.  The issue is it is only defining the very first character of the text.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Typewriter</h1>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.';
var speed = 50;
var x = "" ;
x = typeWriter() ;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {

    x += txt.charAt(i) ;
    
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
    
    return x ;
  }
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x ;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

** This is based on W3School's typewwriter How-To example. [www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com) **

Comment: You only assign `x` to `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML` once. (It is outside of the `typeWriter()` function.)

Comment: Why make something more convoluted than it has to be? If you need a repeating timer, use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval)

Answer (score 1):

You had a few mistakes:

1. most importantly, and the reason you were seeing no updates: the line `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;` was running only once, when the page first loaded. Your `typeWriter` function was updating `x`, but the value of `x` was never being reflected back in the UI
2. you don't want to set `x = typeWriter()`, as this overwrites the empty string that you correctly initially set `x` as, and means your function is trying to add a 1-character string to a function, which will produce a nonsensical result. You don't care about what `typeWriter` returns (which is why I've also removed the `return x` from it - that line does no harm but is completely irrelevant anyway), you just want to execute it, so I've replaced that line with simply `typeWriter()`. The important part is that now `x` starts off as the empty string, as you want.

See working version here with the above points fixed:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Typewriter</h1>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.';
var speed = 50;
var x = "" ;
typeWriter() ;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {

    x += txt.charAt(i) ;
    
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
    
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x ;
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You pointed me in the  right direction!  "document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x; was running only once, "  This was key!  Otherwise, after adding some console log commands, it does actually update the value of x, BUT it's only printed once.  I thought this would change and display the updated value automatically as x changed in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Other way to do the same:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Typewriter</h1>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var txt = 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.';
Array.from(txt).map((v,i,a)=>{setTimeout(()=>{document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML+=v;},50*(i+1));})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why did you minify the JS?

Comment: just giving another option